# RPA Blueprism release file Successfully imported but not visible in processes list

Tags: blueprism

I've successfully imported a *.bprelease file to my Blue Prism environment, but the contents are not visible in processes list.

What can I/should I do to have the contents of the package appear in the list after importing?

Comment: Is it possible there aren't any processes included as part of the release file? It's possible to make packages solely made up of other components, like Objects, Work Queues, Environment Variables, etc.

Comment: What BP version is that? Is it 6.3+ with the Multi-Team environment functions?

Comment: i am using 6.4 versions.

Comment: remaining systems its working, only my system am getting this issue.

Comment: maybe restart blueprism client?

Answer (score 0):

This problem lies in a bug in new version of Blue Prism. It is actually quite common, I've seen this happen for a few people in my team. There are two things needed to know to fully understand the problem:

- Since 6.3 (the multi-team env. upgrade) when you import an object/process that is not in a group, it will be added to a new group called 'Default'
- Blue Prism will not allow you to manually add a group with the name of an existing group (under the same parent group)
- If a group with a duplicate name gets created anyway (by an import or by DB command), one of the groups will not be displayed

And that is what happened here.

The easiest thing to resolve this problem is to simply rename the 'Default' folder you see to something else and then refresh the view (hit F5). You should see a new folder pop-up, with your invisible objects.

Alternatively, you could achieve the same results with a couple of SQL scripts, but this is much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes even renaming the default folder does not work.
It is because there is a previous object (for example) with the same name, but not assigned to any folder.
We have solved the issue importing the object alone, and chosing "renaming the previous version" option instead of overwriting. So, the object is properly imported and placed in the Default folder, from where you can move it to the right one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).